# PostgreSQL: Using SERIAL column and initializing table with subquery

Tags: postgresql

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5c665/1

I've made `products` and `pub_products` tables and trying to copy data from `pub_products` to `products`.

**products:**

```
+--------------+-----------------------+
| Column       | Type                  |
|--------------+-----------------------+
| product_id   | character(3)          |
| product_name | character varying(20) |
| inventory    | integer               |
| price        | integer               |
| manufacturer | character varying(20) |
+--------------+-----------------------+
```

**pub_products:**

```
+---------------+-----------------------+
| Column        | Type                  |                                                            
|---------------+-----------------------+
| hproduct_id   | integer               | <-- serial
| hproduct_name | character varying(20) |
| hinventory    | integer               |
| hprice        | integer               |
+---------------+-----------------------+
```

I want to select `product_name`, `inventory`, and `price` columns from `products` table and insert them to `pub_products` table.

```
INSERT INTO pub_products (hproduct_id, hproduct_name, hinventory, hprice)
SELECT product_name, inventory, price
FROM products
WHERE manufacturer = 'Factory3';
```

But DBMS says "INSERT has more target columns than expressions". Why is this happen? As I know, SERIAL column(`hproduct_id`) of PostgreSQL is auto-increment column, so I  didn't give any initial value. How do I give default values to SERIAL column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that column from the column list of the target table, then Postgres will apply the default value:

```
INSERT INTO pub_products (hproduct_name, hinventory, hprice)
SELECT product_name, inventory, price
FROM products
WHERE manufacturer = 'Factory3';
```